# How to: XML Transformation using POJO and XSLT file

Tags: java, xml, xslt, pojo

I am new to xml transformation.

What I've done is to moved my xml to POJO due to JAVA Heap Space Error due to large XML file.

```
XML + XSLT File ----> XML
```

is this possible doing this? How?

```
POJO ----> XSLT File ---- XML
```

can you give me example. 
Thanks!

Comment: One solution that i've found is that converting POJO to XML via XStream then process with XSLT file to produce XML File. Testing is still ongoing if I have issues with memory processing.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT can't process POJOs, morover, as mentioned in https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/492204-xsltranslation-large-xml-file-using-java-results-outofmemory

> In general, XSLT can't operate as a streaming processor, since its use
>   of XPaths assumes the entire document is available in memory (or at
>   least can be re-read) at once

So maybe you need to try this advice from the same post:

> Sometimes, if you
>   have to process large documents, the only good answer is to drop down
>   from XSLT to a lower level and code the processing yourself as a direct
>   SAX application